# Material-UI Menu,MenuItem in a Table doesn't access its record's values, instead MenuItem has access only to the last record's values

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to put a pop-up Menu as action list for every Table Row. When clicked on "Action", the "handleMenuClick" function always prints "Jan 04" for all the records

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Table,TableHead,TableBody,TableRow,TableCell} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Flex, Box } from "reflexbox";
import Icon from "@mdi/react";
import { mdiDotsVertical } from "@mdi/js";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
const list = [
  { Val1: "Jan 01", Val2: 4000, Val3: 2400 },
  { Val1: "Jan 02", Val2: 3000, Val3: 1398 },
  { Val1: "Jan 03", Val2: 2000, Val3: 6800 },
  { Val1: "Jan 04", Val2: 6780, Val3: 3908 }
];
function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  function handleMenuClick(Val1) {
    console.log(Val1);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <Flex>
              <TableCell>Col1</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Action</TableCell>
            </Flex>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {list &&
            list.map(n => (
              <Flex>
                <TableCell>{n.Val1}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Button onClick={handleClick}>
                    <Icon path={mdiDotsVertical} size={1.2} />
                  </Button>
                  <Menu
                    id="card-actions-menu"
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    keepMounted
                    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                  >
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => handleMenuClick(n.Val1)}>
                      Action
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                </TableCell>
              </Flex>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When I click on the "Action" button it should log the Val1 of its own record.
Material-UI version: "4.1.3"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is,  you have **4 menus with the same AnchorEl** (and their open prop uses the same AnchorEl). 
It's hard to see, but every time you click on any 3 dots:

1. You change the state
2. Re-render is triggered
3. All menus share the same AnchorEl, so all of them open under the same anchor (they are opened in the same place, thats why you only see one opened, but actually all of them are)

---

That's why, when clicking on 'Action', you always get the value of the last menu item rendered (the last one in the array). 
To solve this, create a menu component which manages it's own state and has it's own anchor:

```
const ThreeDotsMenu = (props) => {

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  function handleMenuClick(Val1) {
    console.log(Val1);
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  const {data} = props;
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>
    <Icon path={mdiDotsVertical} size={1.2} />
  </Button>
  <Menu
    id="card-actions-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    keepMounted
    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
    onClose={handleClose}
  >
    <MenuItem onClick={() => handleMenuClick(data.Val1)}>
      Action
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
  </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

And than, from your App component:

```
 {list &&
            list.map(n => (
              <Flex>
                <TableCell>{n.Val1}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                <ThreeDotsMenu data={n} />
                </TableCell>
              </Flex>
 ))}
```

You can refer to this working CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-o9jxr?fontsize=14

Comment: this is completely OK, but how to open another menu when one is already opened?

It takes two clicks to do that - one click to close the existing as part of the popover click and another one the actual click on another menu icon